# What's behind the significant shift in the second series?

Tags: ice-fantasy

The second series, or sequel series to *Ice Fantasy*, *Ice Fantasy Destiny*, seems to represent a massive tonal shift from the first series.

Ka Suo and various other characters have been...reincarnated?...as people in a world very similar to modern-day, real-life China (and the rest of Earth, of course). 
The Ice and Fire lands apparently correspond to Pluto and Mars. Things like that.

There's still a connection with the first series, but it's definitely a change. The ending of the first season seemed to be implying something somewhat different, though I wasn't sure what.

Was this always planned? Was there, at some point, another plan for the second season? Is there any basis for it in the source material, *City of Fantasy*?